# Is it bad to have same domain added in two Heroku apps?

Tags: heroku, dns

I had a domain that was pointing to a particular Heroku app.  Then, I wanted it to point to another Heroku app.

I went into my DNS manager, and I made it point to the new app, but it seems is taking a little while to propagate.  To avoid losing users from the first app, I haven't removed the domains, but I have added them to the new Heroku app.

So if I do `heroku:domains`, for both apps I get the same.

Is that bad? Obviously I will remove the domains from the first app once the CNAME has been propagated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Really? Heroku don't let you have the same domain on two applications because the routing mesh wouldn't know which application to send a request to.